# How Java Control Panel on windows functions in conjunction with many different versions of Java installed on the machine?

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, control-panel

I'm struggling with specifying which one of the many java installations on my Windows 7 machine would be used by the Internet Explorer for (1) running applete as well as (2) for Java web start.

For example, I am going to that Java-View tab in Java Control Panel, change the checkbox there, then make Java Console visible in the advanced tab and then find from the Console header that not always Java which is checked in the Java-View is actually executing applets in my browser.

In Java Control Panel Java-View along with the "User" tab, there is also a "System" tab.
One usually cannot change anything there, but what does that mean, and does it play any role?

In Java Control Panel Advanced tab you see "Default Java for browsers" checkboxes.
Why Microsoft Internet Explorer checkbox there is always checked and always grayed out?
Is this checkbox important or is it Java-View tab screen, which actually affects IE operations?

Also in  jre/bin folder of each java instalation I see javacpl.exe file and can execute each of them, but only one of them, I guess, appears in actual computer Control Panel. How do you determine, which of them is really shown and can be executed  through my computer Control Panel? Does it make sense to do anything with alternative javacpl.exe executables - will their execution affect my IE java-related functionality.

Basically, I'm in total confusion of how this mechanism works, and wwould very much appreciate if someone could give some clarification on at least some part of the above questions. And I'm mostly talking here about  Java 1.6 and Java 1.7, I guess it would be even more difficult if we try to cover in this question also older java versions.

Thanks a lot for any help on this subject.

Comment: I am surprised I see no responses to this question. Am I really the only one struggling with these issues related to Java Control Panel app on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question
 `" which one of the many java installations on my Windows 7 machine would be used by the Internet Explorer for (1) running applete as well as (2) for Java web start."`

```
This can  be tested by making your applets contain Java 7 features like "Diamond Operator". Compile it by jdk 1.7 and then try to run in browser, if it runs then your browser is using 1.7 else 1.6.
```

Second ques -

```
"In Java Control Panel Java-View along with the "User" tab, there is also a "System" tab. One usually cannot change anything there, but what does that mean, and does it play any role?"
```

Answer-   `This is my guess that system tab will contain that option which is configured in JAVA_HOME environment variable OR it can that jdk which was installed more recently installed. Because offcourse default can be only one and not two.`

Third question -

```
     "In Java Control Panel Advanced tab you see "Default Java for browsers" checkboxes. Why Microsoft Internet Explorer checkbox there is always checked and always grayed out? Is this checkbox important or is it Java-View tab screen, which actually affects IE operations?"
```

Answer -    `The option is grayed out because the option is already chosen for you and you need not specify that.`

Hope that helps.